# Defining PWM ports to be used on the GPIO

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, hardware, software-development

I have noted in previous questions and I understand the PWM area of the raspberry pi is the most saturated area, but my question lies in which ports can actually be allocated as a PWM output due to DMA.

[image]
(Sourced: https://www.modmypi.com/blog/raspberry-pi-gpio-en-franais)

I don't wish to damage my board, but from the above diagram other than the ports 18 and 21 which ports can I actually specify to output as a software PWM instead, without risking any damage. This question is more of me trying to be cautious of what I'm doing.

Please forgive me as I'm still learning and any direction that I can be pointed in will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to use PWM (however you generate the pulses) on any gpio on the expansion header.

For a model B:

```
For a Rev.1 board gpios 0-1, 4, 7-11, 14-15, 17-18, 21-25.

For a Rev.2 board gpios 2-4, 7-11, 14-15, 17-18, 22-25, 27-31.

For a Rev.3 board gpios 2-27.
```

Comment: Alright ill look up the rev number, it seems you are the guardian Angel of pwm lol thanks man, just better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: It's probably easiest to look for "mounting holes" on the board,  None is Rev.1, 2 is Rev.2, 4 is Rev.3.

Comment: Fair enough, well im on my way back from work to check my board, because this is something that has been bothering me.

Comment: Ive just worked out my board rev is 000e, for anyone reading this log into your pi and use the command:     cat /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: That means it's Rev.2 in  my terms (gpios 2-4, 7-11, 14-15, 17-18, 22-25, 27-31 on the expansion headers).

Comment: Going to sound really ignorant but the mounting holes are the big holes on the board

Comment: Yes, they should be about 2.4mm in diameter I think.  Yours should have two.

Comment: Yeah it does, hopefully i can ask the really simple questions to save others the pain, you are a legend thanks man